# Istio envoy proxy loging missing fileds

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I have Nginx service with liveness probe, I have enabled envoy logging in istio with JSON format, though another application is able to log correctly, Nginx envoy proxy is missing response_code, protocol field other fields.

```
{"upstream_cluster":"inbound|80|mgmt-80|mgmtCluster","downstream_remote_address":"10.203.128.31:33408","authority":"-","path":"-","protocol":"-","upstream_service_time":"-","upstream_local_address":"127.0.0.1:55290","duration":"0","downstream_local_address":"100.172.68.250:80","upstream_transport_failure_reason":"-","route_name":"-","response_code":"0","user_agent":"-","response_flags":"-","start_time":"2020-01-23T15:02:22.609Z","method":"-","request_id":"-","upstream_host":"127.0.0.1:80","x_forwarded_for":"-","requested_server_name":"-","bytes_received":"114","istio_policy_status":"-","bytes_sent":"844"}
```

nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
    sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx-deployment
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/development/deployments/nginx-deployment
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.7.9
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi, which version of Istio do You have? And on what cluster is it deployed on?

Comment: I'm using istio-1.4.2 and it's deployed on Kubernetes cluster v1.14.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `TCP` protocol You have selected in Your deployment.

```
...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
...
```

According to envoy `v1.12.0` [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.0/configuration/observability/access_log.html#command-operators):

> %PROTOCOL%
>
> HTTP
>
> Protocol. Currently either  *HTTP/1.1*  or  *HTTP/2*.
>
> TCP
>
> Not implemented (“-“).

So the "-" appears because it is not implemented on tcp protocol.

---

You can try to change the protocol to `HTTP` or `HTTP2`

```
...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: HTTP
...
```

Hope it helps.